# Concrete Syntax - String concat in F-Alloy

Tags: f-alloy, lightning-workbench

I would like to know how to concatenate two string or a string and an integer within F-Alloy? At the moment, for loading some images that depend on an integer value, I am doing the following:

```
t.gainAttackPoints = 1 implies i.url = "platform:/resource/MBSD_DSL_Project/DSL/ConcreteSyntax/images/atkGain1.png" 
t.gainAttackPoints = 2 implies i.url = "platform:/resource/MBSD_DSL_Project/DSL/ConcreteSyntax/images/atkGain2.png"
t.gainAttackPoints = 3 implies i.url = "platform:/resource/MBSD_DSL_Project/DSL/ConcreteSyntax/images/atkGain3.png"
```

However, I would like to be able to do it somehow similar to Java:

```
i.url = "platform:/resource/MBSD_DSL_Project/DSL/ConcreteSyntax/images/atkGain" + t.gainAttackPoints + ".png"
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is not supported by Alloy per se. Strings are generally abstracted away as the language is mainly used to reason about concepts and relations.

A way to hack string concatenation in your project is by declaring your field as a sequence of Strings. Concatenation would then consists in appending a string to the sequence.

For your problem however, you do not have the freedom of using sequences of strings as the url field is declared in the LightningVLM model provided by default. It is generally not advised to modify this model.

**tl;dr**

String concatenation not being supported by Alloy, you unfortunately are doomed to provide the image url in one block :-(.
If you want to keep your value predicates clean, you might want to declare a function returning the correct url for a given value of `t.gainAttackPoints`. Function declarations however are not supported in F-Alloy specifications, so you'll have to declare it in the source model of your F-Alloy transformation.